# Using npgsql with SSIS

Tags: ssis, npgsql

I am using npgsql as the ADO.NET provider in SSIS to connect to Postgres and create some workflows.
I am able to connect to postgres but am unable to use the "Table or view" data access mode to list the tables and views. I have to resort to using "SQL command" data access mode.

For the "table or view" access mode, the log shows that the last call is GetDataSourceInformation and it returns successfully. After that there is a close connection.

Has anyone successfully used "Table or view" data access mode using npgsql?

Thanks,

Flash

Answer (score 0):

No, I haven't. I've been using PGNP data provider as I couldn't seem to use varibles at all with the npg ado provider.
I'm having a simular problem with the PGNP provider, - you seem to have to do everything as an expression. Which is a bit rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing SSIS work with Postgres for the last week and I haven't seen that work with either Npgsql or the Postgres ODBC driver.  But, I have a pretty limited readonly user that I'm connecting to Postgres with, not sure if that's a factor.

Answer (score 0):

PGNP provider is greatly improved now and works with SSIS.